# Issue with rails, websocket-rails, websocket, redis + websocket-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis

I am using `redis`, `sidekiq` gem in one of my project and later added `websocket-rails` gem. After that I am having issue something like this:

```
/synchrony.rb:114:in `resume': double resume (FiberError)
from .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/redis-rb-e9e17d65b9c5/lib/redis/connection/synchrony.rb:114:in `block in setup_connect_callbacks'
```

Need help

Answer (score 1):

Use ruby driver instead of synchrony driver for redis. I have forked this project, you can find it here https://github.com/Bivek/websocket-rails and look into latest commit.

Answer (score -1):

you can refernce this documents.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fiber.html#method-i-alive-3F
in my case error was occured like this.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/redis-3.0.4/lib/redis/connection/synchrony.rb:78:in `resume': double resume (FiberError)

so i add

if !fiber.alive?
end

block

thank you